# How can i check every directory in my device in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Is there any way we can check directory and files from root directory with loop process in all its sub directories. I found a code but it needs first directory but i need it to be from root directory.

```
this._storage = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
this.file.checkDir(this._storage, 'mydir').then(_ => console.log('yay')).catch(err => console.log('boooh'));
```

Comment: is "root" directory the root directory of the app right?

Comment: Maybe this helps?

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/

Comment: No, by root directory i meant storage of device. We need to mention folder name (mydir) in checkDir method and listDir method but we cannot listDir from root storage.